# Find all pairs of functions $(f,g)$, $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}, f\left(x(y+1)\right)+y=xf(y)+f\left(x+g(y)\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

> Find all pairs of functions $f,g: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that
>
> *1)*. $f\left(xy(y+1)\right)+y=xf(y)+f\left(x+g(y)\right)$ for all real $x,y$;
>
> *2)*. $f(0)+g(0)=0.$

#### My work so far:

Case i) $f(0)=g(0)=0$

1) $y=-1; x=z-g(-1) \Rightarrow f(z)=-1-\left(z-g(-1)\right)f(-1)$. Then  $f(z)=az+b$. If $f(0)=0$ then $f(z)=z$.

So $$axg(y+1)+y=axy+ax+ag(y)$$
$a\not=0$.

$x=0 \Rightarrow g(y)=\frac{y}{a}$

Hence $$x(y+1)+y=axy+ax+y$$
Then $a=1$, $$f(x)=g(x)=x$$

Case ii) $f(0)\not = 0$

*I need help here*

#### Addition:

Maybe a typo in the book, and the problem looks like this:

> Find all pairs of functions $f,g: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that
>
> *1)*. $f\left(x(y+1)\right)+y=xf(y)+f\left(x+g(y)\right)$ for all real $x,y$;
>
> *2)*. $f(0)+g(0)=0.$

*I need help here too*

Comment: The solution you gave in case i) is not valid: $f(x y(y+1))+y=xy^2+xy+y$, while $xf(y)+f(x+g(y)) = xy+x+y$.

Comment: Sorry for this late comment, but I just noticed that your conclusion: "If $f(0)=0$ then $f(z)=z$" is incorrect. Indeed $f(x) = ax$ and $g(x)  = \frac{x}{a}$ is a valid solution for any nonzero $a$. The rest of your reasoning seems correct though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*There is no solution possible. To see this, putting $y=0$ in (1) gives $$f(0) = xf(0) + f(x+g(0)) \tag{*}\label{a}$$. Now putting $x=f(0)$ in the above equation gives $$f(0) = (f(0))^2 + f(f(0)+g(0))$$ $$\implies f(0) = (f(0))^2 + f(0)$$ $$\implies f(0)=0$$ This also means $g(0)=0$. Now substituting values of $f(0)$ and $g(0)$ in the equation \eqref{a}, we get $0 = 0 + f(x+0)$, that is $f(x)=0 \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$. But substituting this in equation (1) gives $y=0$ which is clearly a contradiction.***(This answer is incorrect since the question was later edited.)**

**EDIT:**

Note that in your proof of $f(z) = az + b$ the fact that $f(0)=0$ has not been used. So this result is true anyway, which almost completes your solution!!. Putting $x=0$ in (1) gives $$f(0) + y = f(g(y))$$ $$\therefore b + y = ag(y) + b$$ $$\therefore y = ag(y)$$. Since $y$ is arbitrary, $a\neq 0$, and hence, $g(y) = \frac{y}{a}$ which gives $g(0) = 0$.